# custom module name is not listed in setup_module table Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I am running on localhostand entry point of my website is `http://localhost.magento2.com/`

1)`config.xml` have  **'`Mastering_SampleModule' => 1,`** but my custom module is not listed in `setup_module` table

commands i used:

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento2.com/public_html$ sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento2.com/public_html$ sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

`module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mastering_SampleModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

REGISTRATION.PHP

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mastering_SampleModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: As Suggestion,PLease remove the code `Mastering_SampleModule' => 1`  from `app/etc/config.php`.Then try it again

Comment: i deleted as you suggested m and run `sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
`

Comment: still setup_module have no entry for this module

Comment: You should first run `sudo bin/magento module:enable Mastering_SampleModule` then `sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Also changes `setup_version="1.0.0"` to `setup_version="2.0.0"` as Suggestion then first run `sudo bin/magento module:enable Mastering_SampleModule` then `sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: ok I deleted `Mastering_SampleModule' => 1` again  changed  to `setup_version="2.0.0"` and run above commands

Comment: stil `SELECT *
FROM `setup_module` where module = 'Mastering_SampleModule' gives  `0 ROWS`

Comment: When you run php bin/magento setup/upgrade do you get any errors?   I've seen this happen when the setup script fails to run because there is bad code.

Comment: i use this command 
    maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/magento2.com/public_html$ sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: and only `Please re-run Magento compile command. Use the command "setup:di:compile"`  comes at end

Comment: Does the module have a setup file for installing something to the DB?

Comment: no only config.xml and registration.php